# Angularjs doesn't function on ie7

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-7

I developed a web application using Angularjs. It function with all browsers except IE7 and unfortunately it must function with IE7.
I followed some guide ma they doesn't function. 
How can I fix my problem?

Comment: AngularJS 1.3 is dropping support for IE8.

Comment: Could have saved yourself a lot of time if you had checked this before you started developing

Comment: This is waay to broad so I'm voting to close, however you may get some mileage out of es5-shim and es5-sham if you stick to Angular 1.2, so I would look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all you need [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

*Note: AngularJS 1.3 is dropping support for IE8. Read more about it on our blog. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier.*